# Wordpress - Generate one PDF of all Posts of single category

Tags: pdf, wordpress

I want to generate one PDF file of all posts of a category. I just found the plugins that creates PDF of a single post. 
I want to compress all Post of a category 'News' in a single PDF/Word file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be:

1. create a template named `category-your_category_slug.php`. [This will make](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display) this template to be used when displaying that specific category. I tested with `category-uncategorized.php` and the url `http://example.com/category/uncategorized/`
2. [modify the query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts) to show all posts:

   ```
   <?php query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   ```
3. if you are in a Mac, it's a matter of printing the page and selecting the option <kbd>Save as PDF</kbd>
   I cannot suggest Linux or Windows options, but this is a matter of a quick googling
4. once exported as PDF, remove the template

---

Or, better yet, you can do the following:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Only modify the query if the url is:
     * http://example.com/category/your-category-slug/?print-pdf
     */
    if( isset( $_GET['print-pdf'] ) ) {
        query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1'); 
    }

    if ( have_posts() ) : 
?>
```

So, only when viewing the URL with an extra `?print-pdf` all posts will be shown and you can use your system print feature, which will be **much better** than any PHP/Plugin option you'll find around (at least, that's what my research showed me).